# Intermittent ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT issues across all apps

Tags: connection-timeout

I have several web apps spread across a handful of different servers that have all been working without issue until a few weeks ago. I've been getting reports of users getting an `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error when trying to access applications.

Here's what I've been able to find:

- The issue doesn't happen to everyone at the same time. One person will have the issue while all the people around them are working fine.
- When it happens, it happens across all domains and subdomains in our DMZ. Internal apps never experience the issue.
- It happens to some users more often than others, like once or twice per day or not at all.
- It appears to be session-related in some way. When the problem happens, any of these steps resolve the issue:

  - Clear cache
  - Change browsers
  - Run ipconfig release renew from cmd

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!